# Is it possible to release a new version of an Android app only in certain languages?

Tags: android, localization, translation

My app is currently available in three languages, I speak them fluently, did the translations myself and can maintain them. And it's a bit of pain. I'm thinking of adding translations to languages that I don't know well or at all (e.g. Japanese). However, there is also a new feature that I'd like to add, which would require additional translation.

If I add the translations now, will it be possible to release a new intermediate version later excluding some languages, so that, for example, the Japanese users would not see the intermediate version with the untranslated feature? I know about staged rollouts, but can they be language-specific?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can upload an update and make it available in the languages that you want to include for this version of your app. This way you can have two version of your app and the users wouldn't understand the difference!